# generate sample dataset over time with python functions?

Tags: python, oop, modeling

trying to use python to generate dataset to practice analysis, imputation with pandas, scipy

i expect to receive a real dataset in the form of an excel spreadshseet with time stamped data (by year)

i'm keen on learning object oriented approach -- 
obsevations will take on 5 features

code below written for 10 observations, but final prodict will be ~ 150,000 over  8 years ~ 1+ million

```
import numpy   
year = range(n)
unique_ID = range(10)
location = numpy.random.choice(a=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], size=1, p=[0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1])
jobs = ['tinker', 'tailor']
age = numpy.random.choice(range(18))
```

i'm using random function to assign certain features, but hypothesize ID with location A has higher chance of job

i'm stuck on how to 'carry' forth model after year 0 IF location doesn't change AND job DOES.

in other words, unique_ID's should instantiate with these features, and will change features based on other functions.

i assume a nested dictionary would be one way to generate final product, but i want output to take the form of what i would expect to receive (xlsx or csv file)

```
def job_assign():
    if location == "A":
        job = numpy.random.choice(a=jobs, size=1, p=[0.2, 0.8])
    elif location == "D":
        job = numpy.random.choice(a=jobs, size=1, p=[0.8, 0.2])
    else:
        job = numpy.random.choice(a=jobs, size=1, p=[0.7, 0.3]

   def run_model():
       for year in range(1):
            for unique_ID in range(10):
                location = numpy.random.choice(a=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], size=1, p=[0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1])  # based on above
            print(str("year: " + str(year), "unique_ID: " + str(unique_ID),
                  'location:' + str(location),
                  'job :' + job,
                  'age: ' + str(age))

def advance_year():
    year +=1
    for n in range(n):
        age +=1
        job_switch()

def job_switch():
    if location == 'A':
        if job == 'tinker':
            job = 'tailor'
        elif job == 'tailor':
            job = 'tinker'
    else:
        pass


run_model()  # then advance_year and use previous unique_ID's....
```

any insight MUCH appreciated !

Comment: You are trying to make a *fake* dataset?  it's not clear what you need, can you write/post in words the specifications for the dataset?

Comment: Yes fake data here in place of anticipated real data.  Idea is that analysis procedures (chi square, logistic regression, etc.) could be applied, mind the result, then tweak function  parameters above to inform how results tables/ figures should be built.